# Миграция почтового сервера QMAIL + COURIER

Tags: post, smtp, миграция

Стоит вышеуказаный QMAIL + COURIER. Его нужно перенести на другой сервер. Подскажите стоит ли оставаться на QMAIL + COURIER, всё-таки QMAIL старый. Или посмотреть в сторону POSTFIX+DOVECOT как на популярную связку.

Или может знаете хорошую альтернативу QMAIL на которую легко было бы смигрировать.

Благодарю за внимание.